# No funciona SendKeys en C# en Visual Studio

Tags: c#, windows-forms, script, vbscript

Quiero una aplicacion que al pulsar un boton, se pulsen automaticamente las teclas Alt+F4 para cerrar por ejemplo el formulario (se que seria mas facil cerrandolo por código y no haciendo que se pulsen 2 teclas, pero es un ejemplo).

En definitiva, no me funciona el SendKeys ya que pulso el boton y no se me cierra el form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("%{F4}");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("%{F4}");
    }
}
```

`

No me funciona de ninguna de las dos formas, ahi estoy solo tratando que se cierre la ventana o bien al hacer doble click en el form o bien al hacer click en el boton. Pero no está haciendo las pulsaciones de teclas. He probado algo tan simple como que al hacer doble click se pulse la tecla ENTER y así hacer que se pulse el boton, pero tampoco funciona.

Saludos.

Comment: El SendKeys envia la accion a quien tenga el foco, si estas presionando el boton sera este quien reciba la accion y no el form, quizas debas usar primero this.Focus() para que el form tome el foco y despues realizar el send key

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con paréntesis

> SendKeys.SendWait("(%{F4})");

Sin embargo SendKeys no funciona en todos los sistemas operativos y no siempre se comportará como quieras. Ten en cuenta que estás intentando enviar estos golpes de tecla a la aplicación, y el sistema operativo generalmente los intercepta antes. En el caso de Windows 7 y Vista, demasiado pronto (antes de que se envíe).

Te recomiendo usar inputsimulator: http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/

Se encarga de hacer todo el trabajo duro de exponer los métodos `Win32 SendInput` a C #. Esto permite enviar directamente las tecla de Windows.

Comment: Yo lo que necesito es que esté en la ventana que esté el usuario, sea cual sea la aplicación que tenga abierta, que se pulsen 2 teclas (Control + G), pero no se ni con que lenguaje hacerlo ni como hacerlo. Por eso empecé haciendo un winform pero no es lo que quiero.